# netbeans rcp install shared modules

Tags: netbeans-platform

We have migrated a legacy product the Netbeans RCP platform and things are going well. Our product is split int two programs. One is used to create data manipulation projects and the other is used to perform the data manipulations.

I am looking at our install at the moment and would like to move common dependancies to a common location and not duplicate them under the install folder for the separate application folders.

We are using maven to handle the dependancies.

This is our current Module structure

- Parent Project

  - Applications

    - App A

      - Application A (nbm-application)
      - Module A1
      - Module A2
    - App B

      - Application B (nbm-application)
      - Module B1
      - Module B2
  - Shared Modules

    - Module S1

Is there a way to specify a common install directory for the shared modules?

Something like this?

C:\Program Files\Product Suite\Application A
C:\Program Files\Product Suite\Application B
C:\Program Files\Product Suite\Shared

And only have the shared modules installed once.

We don't use the Netbeans installer for legacy issues

We use InstallAnywhere to take the nbm-application zip files and extract them to a install location.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.